# Giving numerical value to a package

Tags: package-writing, package-options

I am playing around with making a package for some of my LaTeX commands and environments. The problem I am encountering is that the package will need to take a numerical value, which have a default value if it is not set. So I want to be able to write:

```
\usepackage[XXXX]{myPackage}
```

or

```
\usepackage[val=XXXX]{myPackage}
```

With XXXX being any 4 digit number from 0000 to 9999.

I have looked at kvoptions, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this from the examples I have seen. So what I need is:

- A way for my package to take a numerical value or key-value pair.
- A way to check that the value is between 0000 and 9999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `xkeyval` package sets a family of keys that has the same name like the package.

For this family keys can be defined, like

```
\define@key{mypackage.sty}{val}[100]{%
      \ifnum#1 < -1
      \GenericError{Error!}{The value is not in the correct range}{See blabla}{or other blabla}
      \fi
      \ifnum#1 > 10000
      \GenericError{Error!}{The value is not in the correct range}{See blabla}{or other blabla}
      \fi
      \def\kvmypackage@val{#1}%
    }
```

Package code:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}


\define@key{mypackage.sty}{val}[100]{%
  \ifnum#1 < -1
  \GenericError{Error!}{The value is not in the correct range}{See blabla}{or other blabla}
  \fi
  \ifnum#1 > 10000
  \GenericError{Error!}{The value is not in the correct range}{See blabla}{or other blabla}
  \fi
  \def\kvmypackage@val{#1}%
}

\ExecuteOptionsX{val} % Provide the default value (100 here)
\ProcessOptionsX%

\newcommand{\ValueOfVal}{%
  \kvmypackage@val%
}

\endinput
```

The `\ifnum...` instructions check the value for the range of `[0...9999]`, while `\kvmypackage@val{#1}` is being defined to have the key value later on -- the name of this `accessing` macro is basically arbitrary, but it should be easy to remember and at best have the name of the key in its name, e.g. `\kvmypackage@val`.

The macro `\ValueOfVal` is given for convenience to get the value without needing `\makeatletter...\makeatother`
Calling document:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[val=256]{mypackage}


\begin{document}
Value of val is \ValueOfVal
\end{document}
```

Comment: This work for the check that there is a value and if it is in the right range. But how do I set a default value, if the option is not used?

Comment: @mallereik: See the `[100]` in the definition of the of key -- that's the default value (chosen by me). The `\ExecuteOptionsX` command guarantees that the option is set then, if it is not used when loading the package.

Comment: Works like a charm after the edit, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution using `kvoptions`

The default value is configured by macro `\myPackage@val@default'.
If the value is out of range, then an error message is given and
the value is set to the default value.

The leading zeros can be omitted in the package options, but
the macro `\theMyPackageVal` is normalized to show four digits.

Package file `myPackage.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{myPackage}[2016/04/03]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=myPackage,
  prefix=myPackage@,
}
\newcommand*{\myPackage@val@default}{1234}
\DeclareStringOption[\myPackage@val@default]{val}
\AddToKeyvalOption*{val}{%
  % Error checks
  \ifnum\myPackage@val<0 %
    \PackageError{myPackage}{%
      Negative value (\myPackage@val) for option `val'%
    }{%
      The range for option `val' is 0000 to 9999.\MessageBreak
      \@ehc
    }%
    \let\myPackage@val\myPackage@val@default
  \else\ifnum\myPackage@val>9999 %
    \PackageError{myPackage}{%
      Too large value (\myPackage@val) for option `val'%
    }{%
      The range for option `val' is 0000 to 9999.\MessageBreak
    }%
    \let\myPackage@val\myPackage@val@default
  \fi\fi
}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

% Normalization
\edef\theMyPackageVal{%
  \ifnum\myPackage@val<1000 0\fi
  \ifnum\myPackage@val<100 0\fi
  \ifnum\myPackage@val<10 0\fi
  \number\myPackage@val
}%

\endinput
```

Test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[val=567]{myPackage}
\begin{document}
val=\theMyPackageVal
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result: val=0567]